# Duplicate 'PackageReference' items found. Remove the duplicate items or use the Update functionality to ensure a consistent restore behavior

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, visual-studio-2022, nuget-package-restore

I am using Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022 (64-bit) - Preview Version 17.3.0 Preview 1.1.

[image]

Error

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   NU1504  Duplicate 'PackageReference' items found. Remove the duplicate items or use the Update functionality to ensure a consistent restore behavior. The duplicate 'PackageReference' items are: StyleCop.Analyzers 1.1.118, StyleCop.Analyzers 1.1.118; Roslynator.Analyzers 3.2.2, Roslynator.Analyzers 3.2.2.   Shared.DTOs C:\Users\donhu\source\repos\FSH\src\Shared\Shared.DTOs\Shared.DTOs.csproj   1
```

[image]

Error restoring packages

[image]

How to fix it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Temporary solution: add `<NoWarn>$(NoWarn);NU1504;NU1505;NU1701</NoWarn>` , for example

Old

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <RootNamespace>FSHTemp.Application</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>FSHTemp.Application</AssemblyName>
  </PropertyGroup>
...
```

new

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <RootNamespace>FSHTemp.Application</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>FSHTemp.Application</AssemblyName>
      <NoWarn>$(NoWarn);NU1504;NU1505;NU1701</NoWarn>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

result: restore Nuget package success now

[image]

Long-term solution: Update to new version of Visual Studio 2022 (Stability and.or Preview update channels)

Related: https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/24747

See more https://github.com/unoplatform/uno.todo/commit/6e442d9b1adb8f990139969413344b135714ed93

Comment: For more clear, edit file `*.csproj` . You can double click on name of project to open this `*.csproj` file.